# How do you handle R Data internal to a package?

Tags: r, load, package, internal, rda

The R package I am developing requires several R data objects, such as pre-computed models and parameters.

Currently I have each object in the 'data' directory of the package in individual .RData files. When using the package users can use the "data" function to attach these objects to their environment.

The behaviour I would like instead would be that on loading the package the data objects are automatically attached to the internal package environment and not accessible to the user directly.

My understanding is that placing a 'sysdata.rda' file in the 'R' directory of the package containing the objects currently in 'data' will give me the desired result. However, is there a way to do this so that I can have each object in a separate file instead of grouped together?

Comment: Why put each object in a separate file, why not refer to each object separately? E.g., `packagename:::a` and `packagename:::b`.

Comment: @the_skua Separate files were useful for easier file version management in the package. This was a while ago, but I think I had different model fits as part of the package and sometimes we would want to update one of these but not all of them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `.onLoad()` hook to call `data()` when your package is being loaded, and specify the package namespace as the environment where to load the data objects into.

Assuming you have files `model1.R` and `mydata.RData` in the `data/` directory of your package called `foopkg`, define the function

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  data("model1", "mydata", package=pkgname, envir=parent.env(environment()))
}
```

somewhere in your package (e.g. in `foopkg-package.R`).

After building and installing the package,

```
> library(foopkg)
> ls(loadNamespace("foopkg"))
```

should demonstrate that the various data objects were successfully loaded into the package namespace, i.e. visible to functions in your package but not polluting the global environment.

Comment: This appears to work. Is there any downside to it? I put this in `zzz.R` to load all datasets that are exported:  

`.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname, ...) { datasets <- utils::data(package = pkgname)$results[ , "Item"]; utils::data(list = datasets, package = pkgname, envir = parent.env(environment())) }`

Answer (score 16):

Put your `sysdata.rda` file in the `data` directory of your package.

Do not use Lazy Data -- your DESCRIPTION file should either not have a line for 
LazyData, or, if it does, it should be `LazyData: no`

In any .R file in the R directory of your package add a line like this

```
data(sysdata, envir=environment())
```

I created a `data.frame` named `sysdata` and saved it to a file called 
`sysdata.rda` in the data directory of a package called `anRpackage`

I added the above line to an .R file, and also added this unexported function
just to show that functions in the package have access to the data.

```
foo <- function() tail(sysdata, 2)
```

Then I see the following an R session

```
> library(anRpackage)
> sysdata
Error: object 'sysdata' not found

> anRpackage:::sysdata
  A  B C
1 1  6 a
2 2  7 b
3 3  8 c
4 4  9 d
5 5 10 e

> anRpackage:::foo()
  A  B C
4 4  9 d
5 5 10 e
```

So, users still have access to the data, but as you requested, they do not have *direct* access.  The user still has the option to run `data(sysdata)`.

Comment: This response does not answer the question. I am asking about division of data into different files, not about the data accessability scoping.

Comment: You say you currently have lots of data files in the data directory.  So, add a line like `data(sysdata, envir=environment())` for each of those data files so that they will be "automatically attached to the internal package environment and not accessible to the user directly." Please clarify what you want.